# Different img height/width between WebKit/Gecko when using attribute 'auto'

Tags: css, webkit, gecko

I'm seeing different height and width for an image between WebKit and Gecko/Trident, and am not able to narrow down what is causing the difference, and what should be the workaround.

The page in question is at: http://bloom-site.com/2013/02/15/tesser-well-madeleine-lengle/

The image in question is the big image which occupies the main post.

Could you help, or point me to how I can figure out the CSS properties causing the difference?

Thanks,
Amit

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
img {
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

Works on my side. :)